# добавьте новую функцию, которая читает с клавиатуры пять чисел и отображает их минимум

Tags: java

выводит все время ноль - в чем причина

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;

public class Solution
{

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
{
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    int a = Integer.parseInt(reader.readLine());
    int b = Integer.parseInt(reader.readLine());
    int c = Integer.parseInt(reader.readLine());
    int d = Integer.parseInt(reader.readLine());
    int e = Integer.parseInt(reader.readLine());

    //int minimum = min(a, b);
    int minf = minfive(a, b, c, d, e);

    //System.out.println("Minimum = " + minimum);
    System.out.println("Minimum of five number is = " + minf);
}


public static int minfive(int a, int b, int c, int d, int e)
{
    int res = 0;

    if (a > b && a > c && a > d && a > e)
    {
        res = a;

    } else if (b > a && b > c && b > d && b > e)
    {
        res = b;

    } else if (c > a && c > b && c > d && c > e)
    {
        res = c;

    } else if (d > a && d > b && d >= c && d > e)
    {
        res = d;
    }

    return res;
}

}
```

Comment: А вдруг наименьшим окажется "е"... У вас такой вариант не обрабатывается.

Answer (score 4):

В родных классах Java есть масса реализованных полезных функций.
Вашу задачу можно решить например с помощью сортировки.
Такой метод может принимать произвольное количество аргументов, его легко модифицировать для поиска не только наименьшего или наибольшего, но например второго по значению элемента.

```
public static int min(int ... params) {
    Arrays.sort(params);
    return params[0];  // будет возвращено наименьшее значение
}
```

В вашей реализации большое количество однотипного когда, что отнимает время на написание и модификацию, усложняет чтение и провоцирует ошибки (А вдруг наименьшим окажется "е"...).
Использование встроенных методов является предпочтительным перед самодельными решениями.

Comment: Как по мне, так это самый лучший ответ для начинающего. Он простой и понятный, тут нет 1)коллекций, которые могут быть непонятны новичку
2)стримов, которые могут быть непонятны новичку
3)он легко маштабируемый, не как ответ Nikolay

Answer (score 1):

```
public static int minfive(int a, int b, int c, int d, int e) {
    return Collections.min(Arrays.asList(a, b, c, d, e));
}
```

Comment: дружище полегче  я только начинаю освоить язык

Answer (score 0):

```
package ua.org.oa.nikolajred;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;

public class Solution {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        int a = Integer.parseInt(reader.readLine());
        int b = Integer.parseInt(reader.readLine());
        int c = Integer.parseInt(reader.readLine());
        int d = Integer.parseInt(reader.readLine());
        int e = Integer.parseInt(reader.readLine());

        //int minimum = min(a, b);
        int minf = minfive(a, b, c, d, e);

        //System.out.println("Minimum = " + minimum);
        System.out.println("Minimum of five number is = " + minf);
    }


    public static int minfive(int a, int b, int c, int d, int e) {
        int res = 0;

        if (a <= b && a <= c && a <= d && a <= e) {
            res = a;

        } else if (b <= a && b <= c && b <= d && b <= e) {
            res += b;

        } else if (c <= a && c <= b && c <= d && c <= e) {
            res += c;

        } else if (d <= a && d <= b && d <= c && d <= e) {
            res += d;
        } else {
            res = 0;
        }
        return res;
   }

}
```

Comment: Поменял немного код, вроде работает. Сам начал только осваивать

Comment: А громоздко и немасштабируемо, как и исходный вариант.

Comment: Постарайтесь не только выкладывать готовое решение, но и объяснять что, почему и как.

Answer (score 0):

Предлагаю такое решение

```
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    int[] array = new int[5];
    for(int i = 0; i<5; i++)
        array[i] = in.nextInt();

    System.out.println( Arrays.stream( array ).min().getAsInt() );
```